# Translate Textview by OnLongClick - Where can I find the used Resource of a textview?

Tags: android, resources, textview, translation

I'm trying to implement a special textview, where I can translate the content into a different language. My textviews contains only R.String - Text, so I have the equivalent text in a different language available (I do not have to access a translation server).

How can I get the current String-Resource (R.string.XY) from a textview? Is that possible? Otherwise, how can i solve this problem easily?

One way would be, to set the text programmaticaly, so I can just ask for a Resource-ID in a own method, which I have to store. But I'm trying right now to find a good solution with setting the text in layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own function like this:

```
textView.setText(R.string.XY);
textView.setTag(new Integer(R.string.XY));
```

Then get your string resource ID by:

```
public Integer getStringResourceID(Textview textView){
    return ((Integer)textView.getTag()).intValue();
}
```

UPDATE:

You can try this to get the string resource id which is set in layout file:

```
int resourceId = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("textViewID", "string", getPackageName());
```

Comment: Yeah, this is my current idea too. But how can i solve this problem with setting the text via layout-file?